# How to retain unhover state style on hover state after a delay in my css style

Tags: css, hover, transition

Am trying to define css style in which when hover an element the opacity should change from 0 to 1.after a few seconds if unhover doesnt occur opacity should change its value to 0.

```
.selection:hover .player-icon {
    opacity: 1;

  transition-duration: 3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in;*/
}

.player-icon {
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-top: 21%;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
 opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for this. Add a class on element if a specific time has elapsed and override hover styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use [keyframe animation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

```css
@keyframes show-hide {
  0%   { color: red; }
  10% { color: white; }
  90% { color: white;}
  100% { color: red; }
}

.player-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

.player-icon:hover {
  animation: show-hide 3s linear;
}
```

```html
Put your cursor on the red rectangle more than 3 seconds.<br><br>
<div class="player-icon">Play</div>
```